# Why is CSS being rendered inside CDATA on my page seemingly from nowhere?

Tags: css, asp.net, master-pages, cdata

The header of my master page file looks like this in my code:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Head1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="SmartPeep.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

When I view the site rendered, it looks like this:

```
<head><title>
    Smartpeeps :: Home
</title>
    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

    <!-- Add fancyBox -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

    <!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style2 {
            color: #FF3300;
        }
    </style>
<link href="SmartPeep.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    #SmartpeepMainMenu img.icon { border-style:none;vertical-align:middle; }
    #SmartpeepMainMenu img.separator { border-style:none;display:block; }
    #SmartpeepMainMenu img.horizontal-separator { border-style:none;vertical-align:middle; }
    #SmartpeepMainMenu ul { list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;width:auto; }
    #SmartpeepMainMenu ul.dynamic { z-index:1; }
    #SmartpeepMainMenu a { text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;display:block; }
    #SmartpeepMainMenu a.static { padding-left:0.15em;padding-right:0.15em; }
    #SmartpeepMainMenu a.popout { background-image:url("/Smartpeeps/WebResource.axd?d=rizp0zWlqOPWgeU28unXjfAtIHIHFUu3Rylnmz9M0DW1D3_YMtnoL8fA7gnTmqC_vPI1gxN8QXg-9vknZDLSsY6V8Vc7p_i6k8fLKNrprps1&t=635116993265614829");background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:right center;padding-right:14px; }
    /* ]]> */
</style></head>
```

I have got no idea where to find that CDATA that's rendering that CSS.

The problem is that that CSS is braking my page design around the main site menu.

I'm sorry I can't provide more info but I don't know what more info would be helpful here, I mean I don't know where this comes from...

If I could just edit it or maybe even remove it even, that'd be ideal.

**EDIT**

Here's my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;URL=~/ChartTemp/;"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="SmartPeeps" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
        <clear/>
        <add namespace="System"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
        <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
        <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Xml.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Caching"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Security"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Profile"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls"/>
        <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
        <add tagPrefix="act" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="1048576"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <location path="Members">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <!-- deny unauthenticated users -->
        <allow users="*"/>
        <!-- allow everyone else (authed users) -->
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler"/>
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you show your `web.config` are there any SmartPeep modules configured?

Comment: @GlennFerrie added my web.config file... There aren't any SmartPeep modules anywhere in there though

Answer (score 0):

a good way to test that is to use chrome.

go to the page using chrome. right click inside the page and select "inspect element".

it opens a right side bar - and you can select the html code that is rendered and

it will tell you what CSS is affecting that element and which file is providing the CSS.

In this example - it shows that the css is coming from inside the index.html and from line 10

[image: see image - from chome and example.com]

Comment: It references default.aspx:54 which is in the CDATA block I pasted